# Why do I get a 504 Gateway timeout on /api/me endpoint? (intermittent)

Tags: beatsmusic

I'm getting a 504 Gateway timeout on the /api/me endpoint when supplying the access token exchanged from the oauth/token endpoint. It seems to be intermittent too.

Any idea what this error means or why it would be happening?

Answer (score 1):

A few others have been getting this as well. It appears to be a rate limit issue with Mashery. We've requested they bump up our limit significantly. Are you still getting issues?